# Passing Redux store in props

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux, yarnpkg

I'm doing an University practice building an app using React and Redux. When I start the server using Yarn, I get this error:

```
Passing redux store in props has been removed and does not do anything. 
To use a custom Redux store for specific components, create a custom React context with React.createContext(), and pass the context object to React-Redux's Provider and specific components like: 
<Provider context={MyContext}><ConnectedComponent context={MyContext} /></Provider>. 
You may also pass a {context : MyContext} option to connect
```

My files are these:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import ReduxProvider from './redux/ReduxProvider';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<ReduxProvider />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**ReduxProvider**

```
import { questions } from "../assets/mock-data.js";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import GlobalState from "./reducers";
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

export default class ReduxProvider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.initialState = {
            score: 0,
            finished: false,
            currentQuestion: 0,
            questions: [ ...questions]
        };
        this.store = this.configureStore();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={ this.store }>
                <div>
                    <App store={ this.store } />
                </div>
            </Provider>
        );
    }

    configureStore() {
        return createStore(GlobalState, this.initialState);
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        Hola
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      ...state
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

**reducers.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

function score(state = 0, action = {}) {
    switch(action.type) {
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

function finished(state = 0, action = {}) {
    switch(action.type) {
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

function currentQuestion(state = 0, action = {}) {
    switch(action.type) {
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

function questions(state = 0, action = {}) {
    switch(action.type) {
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const GlobalState = (combineReducers({
    score,
    finished,
    currentQuestion,
    questions
}));

export default GlobalState;
```

By this time, I should be able to at least run the app without any error, but I always get that error with the Redux Store I don't know why. Could it be a problem with the version of any module or something similar?

I'm using yarn 1.12.3 and nodejs v8.12.0

Tell me if there is any other file I need to show.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't pass the `store` instance to `<App>`.  That does nothing, and React-Redux v6 is warning you about that.

In React-Redux v5, passing the store directly as a prop to a connected component allowed, and there were rare occasions when it was useful, but in v6 that has been removed.

Please see my post [Idiomatic Redux: The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/#v6-0) for some details on why that part of the API was removed.

Also, note that returning the entire Redux state object from a `mapState` is usually not a good idea, and if by some reason you *do* actually want to do that, you don't need to spread it - just `return state`.  See [the React-Redux docs section on writing `mapState` functions](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate) for some explanations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was following strict instructions of a guide and I didn't know where the error was. It must be done for v5 instead of v6

Comment: What guide were you looking at?  Even in v5, you should almost never pass the store directly as a prop to a component.  That's mostly only useful for testing connected components without putting a `<Provider>` around them.

Comment: One question: how can I access the store for launching store.dispatch(action) on a child my App component? @markerikson

Comment: You should use [`connect()` to set up prop functions that dispatch when called](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch).

Comment: Yes but I mean, once I have used connect() I only have access to the store on my ReducerProvider.js and App.js components. If I want to call dispatch, can I send the store as a prop to my App child components so they can call dispatch by themselves or should I create a function on the childs that provides the values for the state change to App and call dispatch on the App component?

Comment: You can use `connect` many times, on as many components as you want.  So, you could connect `App`, and any of the components inside of it.  Or, use [`mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) on the parent component to "bind" action creators and then pass those to the children..  Again, you shouldn't pass the store around to components.

Answer (score 7):

React Redux [7.0.1](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v7.0.1) allows passing `store` as a Prop again.

From the release notes:

> We've brought back the ability to pass a store as a prop directly to connected components. This was removed in version 6 due to internal implementation changes (components no longer subscribed to the store directly). Some users expressed concerns that working with context in unit tests was not sufficient. Since our components use direct subscriptions again, we've reimplemented this option, and that should resolve those concerns.

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies on line 25 in `ReduxProvider` i.e.

```
<App store={this.store}>
```

This component is wrapped with `Provider` (which *can* and should accept the store as a prop) and the purpose of this is to make the store available to the rest of the application - so passing the store directly into child components isn't necessary.

To get access to the store, use the `connect` function to connect the component to the store and then [mapStateToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate) / [mapDispatchToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) to access the state and/or dispatch actions.

[More info](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start#provider-and-connect)